# Declaration of iterator traits in C++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator-traits

So to use most standard library algorithms on self-made container classes I've seen that one must declare typedef for iterator traits. Now usually this is done within an Iterator class.

I've always assumed the standard library tries to access the namespace of the iterator by lets say... `container::Iterator::iteratortrait`

But I've now come across the fact that one can simply declare the traits in the container class, and not in the `Iterator` class.

How does the standard library differentiate between looking for the typedef in the `Iterator` class and looking for the typedef in the container class?

Thanks

Comment: please give code example instead of describing code with words.

Comment: "But I've now come across the fact" Are you sure it's a fact? Where did you come across it?